# Is my design for data reading over an I2C bus and writing back to UART good enough?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded

So I implemented drivers for I2C and USART using interrupts with some guidelines online, and was wondering if I can get some suggestions from a design point of view even though the code works (tried at 9600 and 115200 baud rate), but I do get a hardfault upon using two different baud rates at rx/tx. One reason could be i'm using `\r` as an indication to disable the interrupts, and in case of different baud rates, it might not even disable the interrupts since the received byte is different than what was sent. So i'm not sure if I should be concerned with it.

The program:

- runs a loop where it listens for the bytes over UART after the
  control bits are enabled
- triggers ISR for each byte received while storing it into a respective linear buffer, until `\r` is received, indicating the *end of message*
- disables the control bits so it's no longer acting on any new bytes
- parses the data in the linear buffer till `\r`, and does some stuff based on what we receive. One of the things that the program does is read the value off the temperature sensor over I2C and serial it out!

My thoughts:

- I am not sure if I'm making the right usage of interrupts (or maybe I am) cause what I do is enable the peripheral control bits, and then sort of wait for the ISR to be fired (that's application-specific I guess), while storing each byte into the buffer till we get `\r`.
- I am using a linear buffer instead of a preferred circular buffer cause I thought it wouldn't make much of a difference for this application. I am sort of using it a circular buffer (maybe i'm wrong) by restarting the index for storing data into rx buffer to 0; so every time there's a new data, it gets appended from the start. In case of a circular buffer, I'd continue storing data continuously and it would eventually wrap around overriding the old data which has already been parsed by then.
- To make this application more generic, I might need to remove the device address member from the struct and instead pass it to respective I2C HAL functions.

I have included the relevant parts of the code. Feel free to leave a msg if there's any confusion.

```
/* --------------- main.c --------------- */
void I2C_Initilization(I2C_Config_t *I2C_Config, I2C_TypeDef *i2cPeripheral)
{
    I2C1_handle.pI2Cx = i2cPeripheral;
    I2C1_handle.I2C_Config = *I2C_Config;
    I2C_Init(&I2C1_handle);
}

void USART_Init (void)
{
    USART2_handle.pUSARTx = USART2;
    USART2_handle.USART_Config.USART_baudRate = USART_BAUD_9600;
    USART2_handle.USART_Config.USART_mode = USART_MODE_TXRX;
    USART2_handle.USART_Config.USART_parityControl = USART_PARITY_DISABLED;
    USART2_handle.USART_Config.USART_stopBits = USART_STOP;
    USART2_handle.USART_Config.USART_wordLength = USART_8_DATA_BITS;
    USART2_handle.rxBuffer = usart_rxBuffer;
    USART2_handle.rxLength = rxLength;
    USART2_handle.rxSize = rxLength;
    USART2_handle.dmaTransfer = DMA_TX_DISABLE;
    USART2_handle.dmaReception = DMA_RX_DISABLE;

    USART_Initization(&USART2_handle);
}

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();

    /* Initialize I2C config struct */
    I2C_Config_t i2c_config = {
                I2C_AckControl: I2C_ACK_ENABLE,
                I2C_SCLSpeed: I2C_SCL_SPEED_SM,
                I2C_DeviceAddress: MCP9808_ADDRESS,
                I2C_FMDutyCycle: I2C_FM_DUTY_2
    };
    I2C_Initilization(&i2c_config, I2C1);

    /* Initialize USART struct */
    USART_Init();

    StartSerial (&USART2_handle, usart_rxBuffer, usart_rxLength, &I2C1_handle);

    while (1);
}

/* --------------- usart_app.c --------------- */
 void StartSerial (USART_Handle_t *usart, char *usart_rxBuffer, uint8_t rxBufferSize, I2C_Handle_t *I2C_Handle)
{
    char tempBuffer[rxBufferSize];
    memset(tempBuffer, 0, rxBufferSize);
    while(true)
    {
        ReceiveSerialData(usart);
        ParseSerialData(usart, tempBuffer, usart_rxBuffer);
        bool status = ExecuteSerialData(usart, tempBuffer, I2C_Handle);
        if (!status)        // break if "q" is entered
        {
            break;
        }

        // clear out the buffers -- probably don't need it!
        usart->rxBuffer = usart_rxBuffer;
        memset(usart_rxBuffer, 0, sizeof(rxBufferSize));
        memset(tempBuffer, 0, sizeof(tempBuffer));

        // reset the USART state
        usart->USART_State = USART_INIT;
    }
}

void ReceiveSerialData(USART_Handle_t *usart)
{
    while (USART_RxData(USART_RX_BUSY) != USART_READY);
}

void ParseSerialData(USART_Handle_t *usart, char *tempBuffer, char *rxBuffer) 
{
    char *start = rxBuffer;
    char *end = strstr(rxBuffer, "\r");
    uint8_t bytes = end - start;
    memcpy(tempBuffer, start, bytes);
}

bool ExecuteSerialData(USART_Handle_t *usart, const char *str1, I2C_Handle_t *I2C_Handle)
{
    if (!strcmp(str1, "temp"))
    {
        uint16_t temp = GetTemperature(I2C_Handle);
        SendSerialData(usart, "Current temperature: %d\n", temp);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(str1, "q"))
    {
        SendSerialData(usart, "Ending serial\n");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* --------------- mcp9808.c --------------- */
// static variables
static uint8_t txBuffer[1] = {MCP9808_REG_AMBIENT_TEMP_REG}; 
static uint8_t rxBuffer[BYTES_TO_READ];
static uint8_t txSize = sizeof(txBuffer)/sizeof(txBuffer[0]);
static uint8_t rxSize = BYTES_PER_TRANSACTION;

uint16_t GetTemperature(I2C_Handle_t *I2C_Handle)
{
    uint16_t temperature;

    temperature = ReadTemperature(I2C_Handle);
    return temperature;
}

uint16_t ReadTemperature(I2C_Handle_t *I2C_handle)
{
    I2C_handle->txBuffer = txBuffer;
    I2C_handle->pRxBuffer = rxBuffer;
    I2C_handle->rxBufferSize = rxSize;

    // Start I2C transaction
    while (HAL_I2C_StartInterrupt(I2C_TX_BUSY, txSize, rxSize) != I2C_READY);

    I2C_handle->I2C_State = I2C_INIT;

    // read the data from the sensor
    for (int i = 0; i < I2C_handle->rxBufferSize/2; i++)
    {
        I2C_handle->I2C_State = I2C_INIT;
        while (HAL_I2C_StartInterrupt(I2C_RX_BUSY, txSize, rxSize) != I2C_READY);
    }

    uint16_t temperature = ProcessData(I2C_handle->pRxBuffer);
    return temperature;
}
```

Comment: Good enough for what? According to which standard or person? I think results will be opinion-based.

Comment: opinion-based is fine.

Comment: @xyf Opinion based questions will be close per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: ...I mean it's more like a code review where you are critiquing one for certain design choices. The whole thing could've been done in different ways and it working doesn't mean the code is correct.

Comment: And, the answer could literally be a book about how to do embedded programming. I am sure such books already exist. But before this gets closed, I will just add that you have no error checking anywhere. If received UART character is faulty, don't put it to buffer. If buffer is full, stop writing chars to it. If I2C transaction fails, recover from it. But if all your app does is wait for UART commands, and then react to them, I don't see why you need interrupts, because all that your main code does is waiting until interrupts indicate they are done. Oh but this is not a code review site either.

Comment: spot on about error checking. regarding the correct usage of interrupts, I can't seem to picture a scenario where I could do by not having a loop inside `StartSerial()` (i guess correct usage of interrupts) cause that waits till we receive `\r`, and then goes onto parse and execute the input.

Comment: If you just want a code review, you might be better off asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com